# If an exported element is awaited will an importing module receive undefined?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

```
// export.js
let forExport;
(async function () {
    forExport = await Promise.resolve(1);
})();
export { forExport };

//import.js
import { forExport } from "./export.js";
console.log(forExport); // undefined
```

Is this behaviour (`forExport` is `undefined` in `import.js`) well-defined?

I have doubts about it. There are a squashed set of steps must be taken in this case in according to the specification:

1. Call [`Evaluate`](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-moduleevaluation) routine on the `import.js` module.
2. Call [`InnerModuleEvaluation`](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-innermoduleevaluation) for it.
3. Run through a loop of its requested modules: call [`InnerModuleEvaluation`](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-innermoduleevaluation) on the `export.js` module.
4. Perform [`ExecuteModule`](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-source-text-module-record-execute-module) on the the `export.js`. It presupposes suspending the current execution context, pushing the module's one onto the execution context stack and, subsequently, starting to evaluate of `export.js` code.
5. A meeting with the await expression results in suspending of the async function execution. The promise promises to complete it later. The `export.js` execution context is finally removed from the stack.
6. Perform [`ExecuteModule`](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-source-text-module-record-execute-module) on the the `import.js`...

The matter is we do not know when a promise resolving function, which should continue the anonymous async function evaluation (and `forExport` would get `1` value), will be running. All we know is it can be called only [when the execution context stack is empty](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-jobs). However, to my knowledge, the condition is met not only when all these ordeals with initial modules evaluating come to an end, but also immediately after the execution context of the `export.js` module is removed (see step 5 above).

In fact, [`ExecuteModule`](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-source-text-module-record-execute-module) routine uses such instruction as *"Suspend the currently running execution context"*, however it seems to me the execution context stack is actually empty at this moment (?).

Comment: Is your question how to deal with exported promise results, or specifically whether a promise job can get in between two module executions?

Comment: @Bergi the former, but it seems to me if a promise job can take place between execution of modules, it would mean I've got the answer (`forExport` must not be `undefined`).

Comment: "*the condition is met not only when all these ordeals with initial modules evaluating come to an end, but also immediately after the execution context of the export.js module*" - I don't think so. I believe there still would be the top-level execution context of the agent on the stack, which is required for code execution (such as `Module::Evaluate`). It is prepared by the host, see Note 2 in https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-jobs. So no, I'm pretty confident that `forExport` would *always* be `undefined` (as it would be anyway, if the promise was not immediately fulfilled).

Comment: Well `(async function () {     forExport = await Promise.resolve(1); })();` returns a promise which nothing is paying attention to, so nothing waits for it.  IIFEs like this don't let you somehow make an asynchronous operation blocking, it's still non-blocking and asynchronous.  It still finishes sometime later and the interpreter does not wait for it and your `async` function still returns a promise just like they all do.  Other than "top level await" which is supported in some environments, you cannot export an asynchronously retrieved value directly.  You can export a promise.

Comment: @Bergi I incline to agree with you but still consider this moment to be rather ill-defined. The Note 2 is concerned with Jobs computation and it may be not relevant to the module evaluation process. In the other hand, there are such words: 
*Host environments **may** prepare an execution to evaluate code by pushing execution contexts onto the execution context stack. [bolded by me]* (may but not must).

Comment: @Bergi As for me, the primary reason why `forExport` is required to be `undefined` is the instruction *Suspend the currently running execution context* in `ExecuteModule`. It sounds like the spec definetely supposes there is some lower-level execution context in the stack.

Comment: @jfriend00 I realize that when the interpreter evaluates the `export.js` code it wouldn't await that IIEF and just will normally finish the evaluation. However, I wonder if it's possible to execute a promise resolve function (which gives a value to `forExport` ) *before* starting of `import.js` evaluation.

Comment: @Mergasov Yes, I think step 6 (after the suspension of the module execution context) is key: "*Resume the context that is now on the top of the execution context stack as the running execution context.*" I assume that the "may" in note 2 means "must prepare, if they want to evaluate code". And yes, it's a bit inconclusive - in earlier versions of the spec, module execution was explicitly defined to be a job. I guess this was loosened and abstracted a bit since there are many more execution entry points in an actual JS implementation. And in the future this changes anyway with top-level await…